# pushing 500 million + records to oracle db from emr using spark

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, hdfs, emr, parquet

We have got an EMR cluster where the data is residing in parquet format in Hive/warehouse(HDFS). We are trying to push this data(>500m records) to Oracle RDS. The job is getting timed out after running for 3+ hours. At times we also see bad data node exception as well. We are using df.write.jdbc() command to export the data to Oracle DB which is in same/different VPC. Need some help to troubleshoot this issue and how shall we take this forward. We have tried to observe the sql-trace at Oracle end but couldn't find anything wrong.

Since the data is residing in parquet format the data export doesn't work with Sqoop command.

Though when we try to export the data to csv(csv format-> `com.databricks.spark.csv`) file using `df.save()` and then running `s3-distcp` command we are able to export this entire volume of data in ~20mins.

Any pointers in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Manish

Comment: I would export the 500 mln data into csv and then use external table to get them into database

Comment: have you tried apache sqoop?

Comment: You could run a Sqoop export.
[link] (https://www.dezyre.com/hadoop-tutorial/hadoop-sqoop-tutorial-example-data-export)